# screen saver no longer dims the display before shutting it down

Tags: nvidia, 12.10

I have a Nvidia driver for my desktop computer. In 12.04 and all previous versions it would first start to dim and then switch to the off state if I didn't move the mouse for 10 min or so. Since the upgrade to 12.10 there is no longer any hint that it is about to turn off, but rather it goes from 100% to 0% instantly.

Maybe some setting got screwed up in the update? If so, where is it?

Thanks, Ilan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 12.10 there were numerous updates. One of those updates solved the problem and now the display dims as it did in all the versions up to 12.10

Comment: I was a little early here. It did indeed start to dim the screen before shutdown, but now it is back to turning it off immediately. Where is the magic?